# Hibernate unable to retrieve resultSet in production environment

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate

I'm having trouble identifying the issue with Hibernate where Hibernate throws persistence exception.
I've include a screenshot of the code.Sorry regarding the censoring. [Source Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNF9i.png)

Added logs as per Christian's suggestion. [Application logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rpnN.png)

The following are findings which I've done to identify the problem

Production

> Application logs show the following error (javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
> org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract
> ResultSet Application exception overridden by commit exception) Where
> it manages to enter the DAO function but it doesn't show the Hibernate
> query in logs,also fail to exit function. Ran the same source code
> query in production using SQL and it returned expected results.
> Just to clarify: There's another DAO function which uses the same
> tables and it manages to display correctly on production so I doubt it would be a table grant issue

Development

> Records from the query display correctly on front - end when queried
> data is present, logs show that it manages to enter and exit the DAO
> function with the query displayed.  No error even when there are no
> results in database table to retrieve (Logs show the Hibernate query, front-end has no results)

Answer (score 0):

You are not showing the exact error details so it's hard to help. I guess you are setting some parameter to null maybe which Oracle can't handle or maybe one of the functions you are using can't handle the data. The error details you are logging should help you get to the bottom of this.

Comment: As the exception was thrown in the DAO, I'm going to isolate the issue here and attempt to spool the database objects in production to compare